# StaggeredGridView refresh correctly only top

Tags: android, baseadapter

I use https://github.com/bulletnoid/StaggeredGridView this library for make a pinterest style layout and use pulltorefresh on this layout. Also ı have a slide menu for choose different category and according to category which is user choose, refresh and refill the staggred again.

Pulltorefresh is work fine.

if user top of the layout and choose a category on slide menu it's work correctly. But if user bottom of the layout and choose a category on slide menu it's work not correctly .

**the scenario, top of layout and select category on slidemenu and refill staggered layout. it's work correctly**

[image: Top of the layout]   [image]

**the scenario, bottom of layout and select category on slidemenu and refill staggered layout. it's not work correctly**

[image: bottom of the layout]  [image]

-->listviewAdapter

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.listView_sliding_menu:

            smenu.toggle();

            slidingMenuControl = true;
            String categoryId = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.categoryID))
                    .getText().toString();

            parameters[0] = categoryId;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), categoryId,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new PARSEJSONCATEGORYCONTENT().execute(parameters);

            break;

        default:
            break;

        }

    }
```

-->parser

```
private class PARSEJSONCATEGORYCONTENT extends
                AsyncTask<String[], Void, ArrayList<Utils>> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                processDialoge();
            }

            protected ArrayList<Utils> doInBackground(String[]... params) {

                String catId = params[0][0];
                String startCount = params[0][5];
                String count = params[0][6];
                String urlCatContent = "http://212.58.8.109/webservice/api/content/cat/";

                jArray = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrltoCategoryContent(urlCatContent,
                        Token, tokenValue, catId, startCount, count);

                if (utilsArray == null) {
                    utilsArray = new ArrayList<Utils>();

                } else if (slidingMenuControl == true) {

                    utilsArray.clear();

                } else if (contentItemSelection != null) {
                    utilsArray.clear();
                }

                try {

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject k = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        utils = new Utils();

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        utils.imageUrl = k.getString("ipad_URL");
                        utils.imageWidth = k.getInt("ipad_width");
                        utils.imageHeight = k.getInt("ipad_height");
                        utils.categoryHeader = k.getString("contentHeader");
                        utils.contentDesc = k.getString("contentDesc");
                        utils.categoryContentId = k.getInt("id");
                        utils.contentTxt = k.getString("contentTxt");

                        Log.d("ipad_URL", utils.imageUrl);

                        utilsArray.add(utils);

                    }

                    String arrayLenght = Integer.toString(utilsArray.size());
                    Log.d("arrayLenght", arrayLenght);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return utilsArray;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Utils> utilsArray) {

                staggeredAdapter.getMoreItemm(utilsArray);

                // staggeredAdapter.setRefreshListener(false);
                super.onPostExecute(utilsArray);
                slidingMenuControl = false;
                dialog.cancel();
            }

        }
```

-->BaseAdapter.java

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class StaggeredAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

    Typeface tf;
    boolean refreshListener = false;
    Utils utils;

    private Context mContext;
    private Application mAppContext;
    private ArrayList<Utils> mUtilsArraylist = new ArrayList<Utils>();

    public StaggeredAdapter(Context context, Application application) {

        mContext = context;
        mAppContext = application;
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),
                "font/Klavika-Medium.otf");
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void getMoreItemm(ArrayList<Utils> arrayList) {
        mUtilsArraylist.clear();
        mUtilsArraylist.addAll(arrayList);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {

        return mUtilsArraylist == null ? 0 : mUtilsArraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mUtilsArraylist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mUtilsArraylist.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = null;
        utils = mUtilsArraylist.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            Holder holder = new Holder();
            view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.staggered_item, null);

            holder.imgUrl_content = (STGVImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgUrl_content);

            holder.tv_info = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contentHeader);
            holder.tv_info.setTypeface(tf);

            holder.tv_info2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contentDesc);
            holder.tv_info2.setTypeface(tf);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            return convertView;
        }

        final Holder holder = (Holder) view.getTag();

        holder.imgUrl_content.mHeight = utils.imageHeight;
        holder.imgUrl_content.mWidth = utils.imageWidth;
        holder.imgUrl_content.setOnClickListener(this);

        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(mAppContext);
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(utils.imageUrl, holder.imgUrl_content);

        holder.tv_info.setText(utils.categoryHeader);
        holder.tv_info.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.tv_info2.setText(utils.contentDesc);
        holder.tv_info2.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    class Holder {
        public STGVImageView imgUrl_content;
        public TextView tv_info;
        public TextView tv_info2;

    }

    public boolean isRefreshListener() {
        return refreshListener;
    }

    public void setRefreshListener(boolean refreshListener) {
        this.refreshListener = refreshListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.imgUrl_content:
            sendDataItemContentActivity();
            break;

        case R.id.contentHeader:
            sendDataItemContentActivity();
            break;

        case R.id.contentDesc:
            sendDataItemContentActivity();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    public void sendDataItemContentActivity() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ItemContent.class)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("contentTxt", utils.contentTxt);
        intent.putExtra("contentHeader", utils.categoryHeader);
        intent.putExtra("contentİmageUrl", utils.imageUrl);
        intent.putExtra("contentCategoryName", utils.categoryName);

        Bundle animBundle = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(mContext,
                R.anim.anim, R.anim.anim2).toBundle();

        mContext.startActivity(intent, animBundle);

    }

}
```

Comment: StaggeredGridView is an open source project, so why don't you take a look at the source code to see what goes wrong? If indeed there is a bug, then add an Issue, or Fork the project, fix the issue and make a Pull Request. Open source is not only about using someone's code for free but also about contribution.

Comment: Sorry ı suppose someone use this library and contend same problem.Also maybe ı made a mistake to baseadapter or somewhere. I just want to advise where ı am wrong. And thank you for your advise about open a issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i had a same problem with using the same pinterest style library with you. i solve my problem by put this

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    mAdapter = new SearchSTGVAdapter(getActivity(), adsList, (Fragment)this);       
    ptrstgv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

which previously I put it in the onCreate method
For your information, I am implement this pinterest style in a view pager not a sliding menu